# LDAP error: ldap_bind: Strong(er) authentication required

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to connect to LDAP server for my php application. I tried to check active directory connection from putty and it says
**ldap_bind: Strong(er) authentication required**.

**CODE**

```
     [hx10986@sds.hclgss.com@segotl6275 adLDAP_4.0.3]$ 
     ldapsearch -b "dc=sds,dc=hclgss,dc=com" -h ABCDEF80001.XXX.TTTTT.COM -p 389 -x -D 
     "fff\\username" -w 'Password' "( CN=fefefefefef.com)"
     ldap_bind: Strong(er) authentication required (8)
     additional info: 00002028: LdapErr: DSID-0C090273, comment: The server requires binds to 
     turn on integrity checking if SSL\TLS are not already active on the connection, data 0, v657575
```

I tried many ways to fix the issue but had no luck. Any clue how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried enabling TLS on the connection (presuming the server supports it)? So either add ```-q``` to the command line to enable the starttls extension, or swapping to LDAPS by making the port 636 and adding the ```-Z``` option.

Comment: @Buffoonism thank you for your reply. Can you provide me any link?

Comment: ldapsearch command line options are here: https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/tool-usages/ldapsearch.html